# How to convert a general string data such as 29102015 to a MySQL Date type?

Tags: mysql

I've a csv file with a date column which is having data in the format of just numbers. For example: `29102015` is the current format, which means `29-10-2015` (29th Oct, 2015).

The data is as follows in the `iDate` column:

```
iDate
02022015
02012015
02092014
11082013
11082014
13082013
11122013
27082013
```

It contains millions of records in that format.

My expected output of `iDate` is:

```
iDate
02-02-2015
02-01-2015
02-09-2014
11-08-2013
11-08-2014
13-08-2013
11-12-2013
27-08-2013
```

I'm trying to achieve this by trying the following:

First thing is I've already placed the data into Mysql database. So, now I'm trying to extract the date column in a SELECT query in the required date format (dd-mm-yyyy) which isn't working. I tried the following query:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(idate, '%d-%m-%Y') as Inter_Date FROM tf_table;
```

But I'm simply getting NULL as the output for all records.

Second thing what I'm trying to do is while creating the MySQL table itself, I'm trying to find a way if I can directly make the database store the string date in the required date format (dd-mm-yyyy).

Is there a way to do that in MySQL??

Please help me out with these two scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(idate, '%d%m%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y') as Inter_Date FROM tf_table;`

Comment: Thank you so much. But it is giving the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Is there a way I can make it appear 'dd-mm-yyyy'?

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(idate, '%d%m%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y') as Inter_Date FROM tf_table;

Comment: Hey quanton81: Thank you so very much. It worked :))) Please edit your posted answer with the one showed in the comment so that I can select it as the Answer.

Comment: Also is there a way to do this during the `CREATE TABLE` phase itself?? I mean, making the db take the string date into Date format??

Comment: I am not really sure but maybe this would work. CREATE TABLE ... 
INSERT newtable SELECT col1, col2, ... DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(idate, '%d%m%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y') as Inter_Date FROM tf_table;

Answer (score 0):

Just for an alternative you could use something like this (but it is not recommended for millions of records):

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(idate, 5, 4),'-',SUBSTRING(idate, 3, 2),'-',SUBSTRING(idate, 1, 2) ) AS Inter_Date 
FROM tf_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query for the same.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(idate, '%d%m%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y')
```

One more thing you have to understand is the default date format for MySQL is YYYY-MM-DD.